# MySQL - Column Indices or Composite Index for a Select Query With an 'Or' Conditional

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, innodb

I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable 
WHERE columnOne = 1 OR columnTwo = 1;
```

Should I use two column indices(one on `columnOne` and one on `columnTwo`) or a composite index in the order of `columnOne, columnTwo`?

I am using InnoDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A composite index will not help much with this query.  You would want two separate indexes.  However, sometimes `or` doesn't optimize efficiently.

Here is another approach that will work best with these two indexes, `mytable(columnOne)` and `mytable(columnOne, columnTwo)`:

```
select *
from mytable
where columnOne = 1
union all
select *
from mytable t
where columnTwo = 1 and columnOne <> 1;
```